# How to use functions from another controler

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascriptmvc

I am trying to figure out how to use a function from another controller, I steal my controller in the controller where I want to use its functions and then what I have to do ? thanks

```
$.controller('mycontroler1', {
functionToUse : function(){},
});

$.controller('wantToUseFunctionFrommycontroler1, {
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What does "I steal my controller in the controller" mean? And what controller are you using? You should post your actual code you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

This may lead you in the right direction

```
w = function(){
        // returning function i to be used in function2
        return{
            i : function(){
            console.log('World');
        }
    }
}

function2 = function(){
    e = function(){
            // will console log World as stated in function w
            w().i();
    }
    e();
    }
// call function2, which is calling a function within function w
function2();
```